# sql query to replace a range of integer values with a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a column in sql server in which there are integer values, now i want to replace a range e.g values> 55 with a string 'Normal value' and values<55 replace with 'abnormal value', I have tried replace() function but it didn't work. any help please??

Comment: And you want to leave 55 as it is?

Answer (score 2):

The query below doesn't do anything on the table but instead of displaying the value, it displays the equivalent string,

```
SELECT  yourValue,
        CASE WHEN yourValue > 55 THEN 'Normal' ELSE 'Abnormal' END
FROM    tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3032d/1)

56 and up will be `Normal`
55 and down will be `Abnormal`

Answer (score 0):

If the column allows NULLs then you could try:

```
SELECT t.ColA, CASE WHEN t.ColA >= 55 THEN 'Normal value' WHEN t.ColA < 55 THEN 'abnormal value' END
FROM MySchema.MyTable AS t
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ColA INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES(11);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES(111);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ColA) VALUES(NULL);

SELECT t.ColA, 
CASE 
  WHEN t.ColA >= 55 THEN 'Normal value' 
  WHEN t.ColA < 55 THEN 'abnormal value' 
  -- WHEN t.ColA IS NULL THEN NULL
END AS CaseWhen
FROM @MyTable AS t
```

Results:

```
ColA        CaseWhen
----------- --------------
11          abnormal value
111         Normal value
NULL        NULL
```